# Microsoft Word, how to add "(i)" to the dictionary?

Tags: microsoft-word, dictionary

I've been looking around in Proofing and Spelling options in Microsoft Word for Windows for a while and can't work out how to add a word to the dictionary. AutoCorrect is constantly telling me that "i" should be changed to "I", but this is in the context of "(i)" (as in (i), (ii), (iii) etc), and so I want "(i)" to be a defined word. Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: Isn't that the auto list thing kicking in rather than the dictionary?

Comment: I have the "(i)" in the body of a paragraph as opposed to the start of the line, so I guess that's why it doesn't recognise it as such, so I need to somehow add this to a dictionary (or at least, it would be nice to be able to do that). 

Comment: I think that's not so much a dictionary as a grammar thing, as "I" (as in, the first person), is supposed to be spelled with a capital in English. Not sure if grammar rules can be modified as easily (or if you want to, it would mean manually capitalising every 'regular' I).

Comment: In my Word 365 on Windows 10 I am not getting this error. This would not be an AutoCorrect entry but something in spelling or grammar rules. How is Word alerting you that it thinks this is an error? Is it "correcting" it automatically? Note, I have an AutoCorrect entry to change "i" to "I" but it does not apply to "(i)."

Comment: Yes, can you provide screenshots of what you're experiencing?